# SQLite exception deleting row using sqlite-net

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I got tired to search so here it goes my first SO question hoping someone had the same problem and can help me

## Goal

I am trying to store my application data with a SQLite database

## Application description

Windows 8 app C# XAML with local SQLite database using **SQLite for Windows Runtime Extension** and **[sqlite-net](http://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net) library**

## Table definition

```
public class Product {
    private int _id;

    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    private string _date;
    public string DATE
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set { _date = value; }
    }

    private string _desc;
    public string DESC
    {
        get { return _desc; }
        set { _desc = value; }
    }
}
```

## Problem1

`public int Insert (object obj)` description says the following:

> Inserts the given object and retrieves its auto incremented primary key if it has one.

However everytime I insert a row it return **1**. I can sucessfully insert with a auto-incremet ID but somehow it does not return me its ID. Why?

## Problem 2

**I can insert new rows but not delete them**

Working around problem 1 to get last row generated ID, I try to delete rows but with no success.

**See this example test that always fails:**

```
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(_path, _dbname)))
{
    var p1 = new Product() { DESC = "insert1", DATE = DateTime.Now.ToString() };
    db.Insert(p1);
    p1.ID = 1;
    var p2 = new Product() { DESC = "insert2", DATE = DateTime.Now.ToString() };
    // I am sure that this row is getting ID 2, so it will not have a wrong ID
    p2.ID = 2;
    db.Insert(p2);
    var p3 = new Product() { DESC = "insert3", DATE = DateTime.Now.ToString() };
    db.Insert(p3);
    p3.ID = 3;
    db.Delete<Product>(p2);
}
```

As you can see I try to insert 3 rows and delete the second one. The rows are inserted but I get the following **SQLite.SQLiteException** exception:

**unable to close due to unfinalized statements or unfinished backups**

Why? I don't open other connections before and after that.

Thanks in advance

## Solved

### Problem 1

+1 and thanks for @Bridgey for pointing out that function does not match it description and for the relevant search

The function does not return ID as it says but it defines the object ID. So when I insert a new **Product**, **Product.ID** will have last inserted ID.

### Problem 2

I changed `db.Delete<Product>(p2);` to `db.Delete(p2);` and now it works. SQLite-net correctly identify the row as **Product**. I still don't know why the **unable to close due to unfinalized statements or unfinished backups** exception was happening. If someone knows why tell me please.

Comment: I don't think problem 1 is actually a problem. I think SQLite's INSERT returns the number of rows added (1), not the row id of the newly inserted row. Might need: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html

Comment: @Bridgey **Inserts the given object and retrieves its auto incremented primary key if it has one.** You can see this in the method description inside the class

Comment: You're absolutely right, that's what the documentation says, but it looks like there might be a bug. If you look at sqlite-net's public int Insert (object obj, string extra, Type objType) [SQLite.cs], it seems to always return the number of rows inserted.

Comment: @Bridgey Thanks for your help. I changed the function to return me last ID instead. Maybe it will be fixed in the next version. I will try to contact the author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think for problem 2, the issue is that you are passing the Product object as the parameter for the Delete method. The documentation says: Deletes the object with the specified primary key. I think the following should work:

```
db.Delete<Product>(p1.ID);
```

Regarding problem 1, the code of the Insert method of the sqlite-net package ends:

```
var count = insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery (vals);

if (map.HasAutoIncPK) {
  var id = SQLite3.LastInsertRowid (Handle);
  map.SetAutoIncPK (obj, id);
}

return count;
```

As you can see, `count` is returned, even if `id` is set.

**EDIT:** Actually, according to the author this is deliberate.
"Insert returns the number of rows modified. The auto incremented columns are stored in the object. Please see the doc comments."
https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/37

Comment: you're right about problem 1. About problem 2 I already knew that I could delete by its ID. But what I was trying to do is deleting by object. See my edited question. Thanks for your help, you have my vote